# not able to get collection from local mongoDB while using routes controllers and model separate files

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```js
// app.js file

const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const courseRouter = require('./routers/courseRouter');
const app = express();

///  middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.json());

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('from middle ware');
    next();
});

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('from  second middle ware');
    next();
});
///  routes

app.use('/courses',courseRouter);

module.exports = app;


//////////////// server.js file

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = require('./app');
dotenv.config({path:"./config.env"});

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_LOCAL,{
  useNewUrlParser:true,
  useCreateIndex:true,
  useFindAndModify:false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true

}).then(con =>console.log(con.connections));

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log(` App running at port 3000`);
});
/////////////////courseRouter.js file

const express = require('express');
const courseController = require('./../controlers/courseController');

const router = express.Router();


router.
 route('/courses').
 get(courseController.getCourses);


 module.exports = router;
 
 //////// coursecontroller.js file
 const Course = require('./../models/course.model');

exports.getCourses = async (req,res)=>{
    try{
   const courses = await Course.find({});

   res.status(200).json({
       status:'sucess',
       data:{
           courses
       }
   })

    } catch (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get simple get response from local mongoDB which is running at localhost:27017.

In there I have winrobot DB with collection courses which have one document.

So, my server is listening at port 3000, I have divided my routes , controllers and model according to MVC.

When I tried to get courses collection, I get "GET /courses 404 14.068 ms - 146" this morgan request log.but if I delete these controller and routes and implement that in `app.js` that works fine... so I want routes and controller in different files and still get courses collection.[added the github repo of same code](https://github.com/suresheerf/win-back.git)

Comment: It's better to provide your code example here

Comment: Suresh, welcome to SO. Please edit your question. Make it readable. Put the code with question. If it's unreadable, you're likely to get no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line:

```
app.use('/courses',courseRouter);
```

But then you are defining the router in the course file:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.
 route('/courses').
 get(courseController.getCourses);
```

Basically what ends up happening is you create a route that looks like:

```
/courses/courses/
```

You should change this:

```
router.
 route('/').
 get(courseController.getCourses);
```

Now your app will use the router you created properly.

Comment: I used that router in app.js file at last to second line like app.use('/courses', courseRouter)...... In which courseRouter required from courseRouter.js file where it exports router.

Comment: Ah my bad, i edited my answer to reflect the real problem